# What is the purpose of those friendly big plant looking creatures?

Tags: forager

Not sure how best to describe them. There is a big momma type one and 2-3 baby ones. They look like big fat plants and they have a creepy love towards me. If you hit them they say something like "ouch, but we still love you".

1. Can they be killed?
2. Is there any negatives to killing them?
3. Is there any positives for leaving them be?

Basically, they take up a lot of prime real estate that I would prefer to use for something else. But I feel bad when I accidentally hit them so I haven't tried to kill them (plus I don't want to lock out any potential reward).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Yes (but how could you think about doing something so horrible)

2.Your guilt at being such a horrible person might keep you awake at night

3.You have some friendly Beet friends

If you kill them you get a Feat and a couple of beets. Its up to you if the weight on your conscious is worth the reward

Comment: Ok, so how about instead of killing them I just gently poke them back into the ground so they are safe from all those pesky green slimes that are jumping all over the place? Yeah, I think I will do that, repeated poke them with my pickaxe until they are back safe underground...

Comment: But yeah thanks. I didn't realise there was a feat for it (not really looked through them properly yet). I think that is enough to convince me it's ok :)